# Bot framework Hero card without image parameter

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots

How to avoid the image parameter in Hero card bot framework so that I can display only the options.
following code is not working, only BotFramework Hero Card title is diplaying
`createHeroCard() {
        return CardFactory.heroCard(
            'BotFramework Hero Card',
            CardFactory.actions([
                {
                    type: 'imBack',
                    title: 'ABC',
                    value: 'ABC'
                },
                {
                    type: 'imBack',
                    title: 'DATA',
                    value: 'DATA'
                },
            ])
        );
    }`

Comment: Hello is there anything else that I can help you with?

Answer (score 0):

I am noob at node.js I did same on C# which worked as expected. You could try converting the same. Here is the code snippet for your assistance.

```
public IMessageActivity YesCreateSolutionFlow()
    {
        try
        {
            var yesNoActivity = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
            var buttonList = new List<CardAction>();
            //Btn 1
            buttonList.Add(
           new CardAction()
           {
               Value = "https://partner.microsoft.com/en-US/solutions/my-solutions/create-solution",
               Type = "openUrl",
               Title = "Yes, please"
           });
            //Btn 2
            buttonList.Add(
           new CardAction()
           {
               Value = "I Would like a tutorial first",
               Type = "imBack",
               Title = "I Would like a tutorial first"
           });
            var responseCard = new HeroCard()
            {
                Text = "",
                Subtitle = string.Empty,
                Buttons = buttonList
            };

            // Create the attachment.
            var attachment = responseCard.ToAttachment();

            yesNoActivity.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            yesNoActivity.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
            return yesNoActivity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }

    }
```

Finally, pass this card on `turnContext.SendActivityAsync` like below:

```
      var yesCreateSolutionFlow= _customFlowRepository.YesCreateSolutionFlow();
      await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(yesCreateSolutionFlow).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**`Bot Conversation Output:`**

[image]

Hope that would help.

Answer (score 0):

[CardFactory.heroCard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/cardfactory?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#herocard-string--string---cardimage----string---cardaction----partial-herocard--) is expecting 3 or 4 parameters, You have only provided 2, so I believe the method is trying to interpret your buttons as images. if you pass an empty array as your second argument, I believe it will work as expected i.e.

```js
    createHeroCard() {
        return CardFactory.heroCard(
            'BotFramework Hero Card',
            [],
            CardFactory.actions([
                {
                    type: 'imBack',
                    title: 'ABC',
                    value: 'ABC'
                },
                {
                    type: 'imBack',
                    title: 'DATA',
                    value: 'DATA'
                },
            ])
        );
    }
```

If you don't want a title at all, you can just pass a blank string (i.e. `''`) as the first argument.